# Can I test code not contained within a class with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I  want to test some functions in a php file, but that code is not in a class. Can I still test it with PHPUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a utility class that calls the functions.

```
class GlobalFunctions {
    public function call_your_function($a, $b, $c) {
        return yourfunction($a, $b, $c);
    }
}
```

And then write tests for that class.